# WordPress archive.php page not showing posts, but showing title of current page

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I actually struggling with problem on this URL: [Problematic URL](https://gamesquad.cz/herni-clanky/)

The problem can be described like this:
Page on that URL was set as main blog page in WordPress settings, but the page does not output list of posts, it just only outputs name of page "Herní články" and button read more (číst více) links to this page.. article id="post - id" showing classes "page type-page" and I really don't know how to resolve this problem..
The archive.php code is here:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php 
    $title_style = 'margin-bottom: 50px;';
    $blog_content_style = 'margin-bottom: 30px;'; 

?> 


<div id="primary" class="blog-content-area archive" style="<?php echo esc_attr($blog_content_style); ?>">
<?php 

$title_color = (!empty($tdl_options['tdl_blog_title_color_scheme'])) ? $tdl_options['tdl_blog_title_color_scheme'] : 'mta-light';


    $default_image_header = "";

    if ( (isset($tdl_options['tdl_blog_default_header_bg']['url'])) && (trim($tdl_options['tdl_blog_default_header_bg']['url']) != "" ) ) {
        $default_image_header = $tdl_options['tdl_blog_default_header_bg']['url'];
    }

    if ($default_image_header) {
        $header_content_type = 'image';
        $image_header = $default_image_header;
    } else {
        $header_content_type = '';
    }
 
    $title_align = $tdl_options['tdl_blog_title_align'];
?>


    <?php 

    if ($header_content_type == 'image')      
        echo '<div class="site_header with_featured_img' . $no_parallax . '" style="' . $title_style . 'background-image:url(' . $image_header . ')">';          
    else 
        echo '<div class="site_header  without_featured_img ' . $title_color . '" style="' . $title_style . '">';
    ?>

        <div class="site_header_overlay"></div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 <?php echo esc_attr( $title_align );?> large-centered columns">
                    <?php 
                    if ((isset($tdl_options['tdl_shop_breadcrumb'])) && ($tdl_options['tdl_shop_breadcrumb'] == "1"))
                        {
                        // BREADCRUMBS
                        echo woodstock_breadcrumbs();
                        }
                    ?>


                        <h1 class="page-title on-shop">
                            <?php
                                if ( is_category() ) :
                                    single_cat_title();
        
                                elseif ( is_tag() ) :
                                    single_tag_title();
        
                                elseif ( is_author() ) :
                                    /* Queue the first post, that way we know
                                     * what author we're dealing with (if that is the case).
                                    */
                                    the_post();
                                    printf( esc_html__( 'Author: %s', 'woodstock' ), '<span class="vcard">' . get_the_author() . '</span>' );
                                    /* Since we called the_post() above, we need to
                                     * rewind the loop back to the beginning that way
                                     * we can run the loop properly, in full.
                                     */
                                    rewind_posts();
        
                                elseif ( is_day() ) :
                                    printf( esc_html__( 'Day: %s', 'woodstock' ), '<span>' . get_the_date() . '</span>' );
        
                                elseif ( is_month() ) :
                                    printf( esc_html__( 'Month: %s', 'woodstock' ), '<span>' . get_the_date( 'F Y' ) . '</span>' );
        
                                elseif ( is_year() ) :
                                    printf( esc_html__( 'Year: %s', 'woodstock' ), '<span>' . get_the_date( 'Y' ) . '</span>' );
        
                                elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-aside' ) ) :
                                    esc_html_e( 'Asides', 'woodstock' );
        
                                elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-image' ) ) :
                                    esc_html_e( 'Images', 'woodstock');
        
                                elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-video' ) ) :
                                    esc_html_e( 'Videos', 'woodstock' );
        
                                elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-quote' ) ) :
                                    esc_html_e( 'Quotes', 'woodstock' );
        
                                elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-link' ) ) :
                                    esc_html_e( 'Links', 'woodstock' );
        
                                else :
                                    esc_html_e( 'Archives', 'woodstock' );
        
                                endif;
                            ?>
                        </h1>

                        <?php
                            // Show an optional term description.
                            $term_description = term_description();
                            if ( ! empty( $term_description ) ) :
                                printf( '<div class="term-description"><p>%s</p></div>', $term_description );
                            endif;
                        ?>                        

                    
            </div><!-- .large-12 -->

        </div><!-- .row -->

    </div><!-- .site_header -->
        
        
        <?php if ( $blog_with_sidebar == "yes" ) : ?>
            <div class="row"><div class="large-8 columns with-sidebar">
        <?php endif; ?>
        
                <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
                
                    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                
                                    
                        <!--masonry style-->
                        <?php if ( $blog_with_sidebar == "blog-masonry" ) : ?>
                            
                            <div class="blog-isotop-master-wrapper">
                            
                                <div class="row">
                                <div class="large-12 columns">
                                
                                    <div class="blog-isotop-container">
                            
                                        <div id="filters" class="button-group">
                                            <button class="filter-item is-checked" data-filter="*">show all</button>
                                        </div>
                            
                                        <div class="blog-isotope">
                                            <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
                                
                                            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>

                                            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                                    
                                                <div class="blog-post hidden <?php echo get_post_format(); ?>">
                                                    <div class="blog-post-inner">

                                                        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/content', get_post_format() ); ?>
                                    
                                                        <hr class="content_hr" />
                                                               
                                                    </div><!--blog-post-inner-->
                                                </div><!-- .blog-post-->
                                
                                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                                
                                        </div><!-- .blog-isotope -->
                                        
                                    </div><!-- .blog-isotop-container-->
                                    
                                </div><!--.large-12-->
                                </div><!--.row-->
                                
                                <?php woodstock_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>
                            
                            </div><!--blog-isotop-master-wrapper-->
                            
                        <!--default style-->    
                        <?php else : ?>
                        <?php if(is_author()) {
                            echo '<h1 class="author-name">Články od autora: '.get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id).'</h1>';
                            echo '<div class="author-description">'.get_the_author_meta('description', $author_id).'</div>';

                         } ?>
                            
                            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                                
                                    
                                    <?php get_template_part( 'includes/content', get_post_format() ); ?>
                                    
                                    <hr class="content_hr" />
                                    
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                
                            <?php woodstock_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>
                            
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    
                    <!--no posts found-->
                    <?php else : ?>
            
                        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
            
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    
                </div><!-- #content --> 
                         
            <?php if ( $blog_with_sidebar == "yes" ) : ?>
                </div><!-- .columns -->
            <?php endif; ?>
            
            <?php if ( $blog_with_sidebar == "yes" ) : ?>
                <div class="large-4 columns">                           
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="large-10 large-push-2 columns">                 
                                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>                
                </div><!-- .columns -->
            <?php endif; ?>
            
        <?php if ( $blog_with_sidebar == "yes" ) : ?>
            </div><!-- .row -->
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( $blog_with_sidebar == "yes" ) : ?>
        <?php if (is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar')) : ?>
                <div id="button_offcanvas_sidebar_left"><i class="sidebar-icon"></i></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
                            
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Same code works well on this [URL](https://royalvape.cz/blog/)
I've already tried update WordPress but it still doesn't work, so I'm helpless..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was resolved by switching theme, so, it was maybe some bug in WP.